# Название компонента

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Мне нужно узнать название компонента.
Снизу появляется такое количество точек, сколько мини экранов создано. И между ними можно переключаться проведя пальцем влево-вправо. Примерно также реализовано переключение между рабочими столами на андроиде. Кривовато вопрос сформулировал, но надеюсь меня поймут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компонент, который "листает", это стандартный [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). А вот если нужны ещё и точки, то нужно подцепить `PageIndicator`.

Ещё [статья](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html) по теме.

Comment: спасибо!
вы молодец

Comment: @zimper - если ответ нравится то надо кликать на иконку нравится (с левой стороны ответа) - так здесь принято.

Comment: Недостаточно очков уважения

Answer (score 3):

[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: благодарен.

Comment: @zimper - если ответ нравится то надо кликать на иконку нравится (с левой стороны ответа) - так здесь принято.